# dispersion relation of $i\epsilon_{t}+\epsilon_{xx}+2(d_{1}^2+b_{2}^2)(\epsilon+\epsilon^\ast)+4d_1b_2\epsilon+4d_1b_2^2=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dispersive-pde

For $\epsilon=\epsilon(x,\;t)$, I have

$i\epsilon_{t}+\epsilon_{xx}+2(d_{1}^2+b_{2}^2)(\epsilon+\epsilon^\ast)+4d_1b_2\epsilon+4d_1b_2^2=0, \;\;\; (1)$

where $d_1,\;b_2$ are constants, and $\epsilon_{t}$ is the derivative w.r.t $t$. If the last term in equation $(1)$ is not present then for

$\epsilon=\epsilon_1e^{i(kx-wt)}+\epsilon_2e^{-i(kx-wt)}$

we can get dispersion relation between wave number $k$ and frquency $w$. But if the last term is present in equation $(1)$ then I am not able to find the dispersion relation for frquency $w$ and wave number $k$. Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Why can't you get the dispersion relation if the last term is present?

Comment: Because there is no $\epsilon$ in the last term.

Comment: @mattos, do you know how to get dispersion relation of (1)?